# Update my 1020 to windows 10

Tags: windows-10-mobile, nokia-lumia-1020

I Can't get W10M update on my 1020 using neither upgrade advisor nor insider (in all 3 rings). MSoft is not providing updates for phones with s4 processors, and i know it. But, can I tweak my phone to get update, threshold or redstone, anything?

Answer (score -2):

You can join insider preview/program to get windows10, since it is not stable not recommended to use in main mobile or daily use

http://www.windowscentral.com/how-join-windows-insider-program]

Comment: As far as I know, old x20 series devices can no longer get W10M through Windows Insider.

Comment: And I don't think the 1020 ever did

Comment: i used this method, i got win 10 on my phone. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=knUK2gdp2u4&lc=z12uthyavln1tpn1r223e3hwssn4dbw2t